# How to create function with options of arguments?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Create a function that can have different argument list.
something like this

```
void s(int d, double t);
void s(string d, UNIT e);
```

thanks in advance.
**Edit 2:**
Okay, when i try it with my class it doesn't work...
here is my base class

```
class GUIInterface
{
public:
    .....
    virtual void LoadFile(string fileName) = 0;
    virtual void LoadFile(LPCWSTR fileName) = 0;
        ....
};
```

I get this error.

```
error C2259: 'GUIButtons' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'void GUIInterface::LoadFile(LPCWSTR)' : is abstract
```

Okay, in my GUIButtons i override the `virtual void LoadFile(string fileName) = 0;` but i don't override the second one.
like this

```
class GUIButtons : public GUIInterface
{
     .....
     void LoadFile(string fileName) { ... }
     ...
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. C++ allows multiple definition of the function s as long as each has a unique set of parameters.

Comment: Oh forgot to include something in my post, how about if the functions are virtual and in class

Comment: @Ramhol - What about it?

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with overloading. See my amended answer.

Comment: You just need to provide an implementation for the function `GUIButtons::LoadFile(LPCWSTR)`.  You made it pure virtual (with `= 0`, which tells the compiler to insist that derived classes provide their own implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function overloading is perfectly legal in C++, as long as the parameters can produce a unique resolution. In the above case, the first parameter will always be sufficient to resolve uniquely to one of the functions.

In a class context, if the member functions are defined in the same class, it works just as it does for free functions.

The one scenario that catches out many C++ novices is with inheritance:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void s(int d, double t);
};

class Bar {
public:
    void s(string d, UNIT e);
};

// ...

Bar b;
b.s("hello", 42); // Fine
b.s(3, 4.5);      // FAIL
```

The second call tp `b.s` won't work, because C++ looks for the first scope that contains the symbol. In this case, it finds `Bar::s`, and even though `Bar::s(string, UNIT)` fails the match, C++ won't go and try the base class. Once a scope with the symbol is found, the search stops there and then, regardless of whether a matching function is found at that point.

You can get around this behaviour by explicitly reintroducing the base class symbol in the derived class:

```
class Bar {
public:
    using Foo::s;
    void s(string d, UNIT e);
};
```

**EDIT:** In response to the OP's Edit 2...

The problem you are seeing has nothing to do with overloading. You simply haven't *overridden* the pure virtual member functions in the derived class `GUIButtons`. Overriding a base-class function with a matching derived-class function is a different concept to overloading.